# codeigniter:how to check user name and password

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

if login failed then how to redirect same login page & display wrong username
                  
                        $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var uname = $('#uname').val();
                            var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
                            if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
                            {
                                $('#errmessage').show().html('All Fields are required');
                            } else {
                                $('#errmessage').html("").hide();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "User_controller/login_autho/",
                                    datatype: 'json',
                                    data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        $('#successmessage').fadeIn().html(data),
                                                window.location.replace("/User_controller/profile");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    
To check login autho and if success then redirect to profile page

```
public function login_autho() {
                $data = array(
                    'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                    'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
                );

                $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);

                if ($result == TRUE) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success Login');
                    $this->load->view('user/success');
                 //   echo 'su';
                } else {
                    //$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
                    //echo 'invalid user';
              // echo json_encode(false);
                    }
            }

            public function profile() {
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('user/success');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple to write on

```
$uname = $this->input->post('uname');
  $upassword = $this->input->post('upassword');
```

Pass these variables to model function

```
$this->Model->login($uname,$upassword); // Login method you have to create

if($query->count() ==1  ){
    echo  'login';
    }else{
    echo "failed";
    }
```

Then check in database

$query =   $this->db->query('SELECT  * FROM  'your_table_name' WHERE 'uname'= $uname AND 'password' = $upassword '); // Query modify as per ur requirement

return $query->count();

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
 $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
    $upassword = $this->input->post('upassword');
    $result= $this->Model->login($uname,$upassword); // Login method you have to create
   if($result=='login'){
       header('location:dashbord.php');
    } else {
      header('location:index.php?error=1');
   }
```

Modal

```
public function login($uname,$upassword){
    $query =   $this->db->query('SELECT  * FROM  'your_table_name' WHERE uname='. $uname. ' AND password='. $upassword); // Query modify as per ur requirement

    if(count($query) ==1  ){
        echo  'login';
        }else{
        echo "failed";
        }

}
```